# Aligning items using display: inline-block;

Tags: html, css, inline

I have a problem that i don't know how to fix.

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sjr2yqc/1/) code.

I don't know how to  get all of the items inside the top bar properly.
There also happens a strange thing: when i put some text inside the ID=toplogo, all the elements shift a bit. What causes this problem and how can i fix it?

```
please help
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1sjr2yqc/5/ do u need like this?

Answer (score 1):

Edited your fiddle.

Basically I added:

```
overflow:hidden
```

..to your inline-blocks and set

```
line-height = height of block
```

..to align the text instead of using padding.

Check out the edits [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kwd25w45/)

Comment: thanks, you really helped me. I still need to learn these basic tricks

Answer (score 0):

why you use padding-top for those login and signup ?

It is suggested to use `<ul>` instead of div's for menu

You want to achieve like this ?

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2cxxzdo/)